# What triggers Always On Display's display of seconds?

Tags: samsung, screen, clock

I'm using a Samsung A320F/DS with AOD in "show always" mode. Android is 8.0.0, AOD has only a single page (without the player). Clock style is set up as

```
  22:59
TUE 3 JULY
  84%
```

But one day, when I extracted my phone from the pocket, I found it displaying time as `12:00:41`, changing seconds every second. I didn't pay attention at first, and hid the phone back into the pocket. After some time, when I extracted it again to use, the seconds appeared to have gone.

But now I wonder: what triggered this display of seconds? How do I reproduce this? I've tried tapping everywhere, pressing sensor buttons at the bottom, holding them, pressing/holding menu button, volume buttons, but the phone didn't react.

EDIT: I've found that on the Lock Screen, I can get seconds by tapping the clock area. Then the screen dims a bit, and the clock begins to display seconds — until the screen turns off. I still wonder how I triggered this in the Always On Display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, what I saw was not the Always On Display. I suppose the sequence of events was something like follows:

1. While the phone was in the pocket, power button got pressed
2. Due to hot weather the touchscreen was activated by the side of the pocket (wetted due to sweat), thus tapping OK in the warning dialog to "continue using the phone"
3. The same activation mechanism resulted in a tap on the clock area on the Lock Screen
4. Lock Screen presented its "extended clock" or whatever it's called, which shows seconds — on a very dimmed out background.

The dimmed background is likely what made me think it's completely black and assume that it's the Always On Display.

And indeed, this agrees with my observation that after several seconds the extended clock format changes back to the MM:SS — this is simply the display going to sleep, turning on the real AOD.